# Database for storing a large log table

Tags: sql-server, azure, data-warehouse, powerbi, nosql

We have an API server running that serves around 500.000 requests a day. We want to keep all these reguests in a database to be able to analyze the data. We log things like:

- Who did the request
- How long time did it take
- Date and time
- Http response code
- What api resource was asked for (url)
- Cached response or not (bool)
- +++

We want to keep these logs for 3 months, something which will result in about 45.000.000 records in that database. When records are older than 3 months they are deleted.

Storing these 45 million records in a sql database is possible, but then it is really slow to perform any analysis on these data. We would like to do extensive analysis like - how many request did a specific user do today, compared to the same day last week? How many percent of requests failed today compared to any other day? See a trend diagram showing if the number of request are going up or down. See the top 10 resources being asked for at a given time. You get it - we want to be able to do all kind of analysis like this.

Can you give any advise on where to store these logs to be able to do analysis like this in realtime (or near realtime)? Any nosql database that could be good for this? Azure? I see there is something called azure sql datawarehouse, could that be used for this? I have looked at Microsoft Power Bi which will probably be great for doing the analysis on these data, but where do I store the data.

I would really appreciate if someone have some suggestions for me.

Comment: Why did you write that sql server is slow managing 45 M records? For a well configured sql-server, 45 M rows are a low amount of data.

Comment: It can handle the 45 millions records - I have tested it, but doing all kind of aggregations is slow (like grouping on user and resourcerl and count the rows with an error-code is taking a long time). So even if it may be possible to do this with a regular sql server if I spend enough time on tuning it, I feel it is not the correct tool in this case.

Comment: For SQL Server at 45m rows, you definitely need indexes to support your queries, e.g. on Foreign Key and commonly filtered columns (user, resourcerl, error-code). Columnstore indexes give the best performance. You could also look into partitioning the table e.g. on date.  This adds to your ETL complexity but speeds queries by reducing I/O.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Power BI is potentially a good solution for you.  It actually spins up a SQL Server Analysis Services instance in memory, which is effectively an "OLAP data warehouse".  Infrastructure requirements are minimal as you design in a free PBI Desktop tool and publish to Microsoft's cloud for PBI Web users.

There are limits to the data that can be published - see link below.  Note that PBI uses the very effective Vertipac compression so datasets are typically a lot smaller than your raw data. I often see 10k - 50k rows per MB, so 45m should be achievable with a single Pro license.  Ruthlessly filter your column list in PBI Desktop to optimise this.

https://powerbi.microsoft.com/en-us/documentation/powerbi-admin-manage-your-data-storage-in-power-bi/

With PBI Pro license you can refresh Hourly, up to 8 times a day:

https://powerbi.microsoft.com/en-us/documentation/powerbi-refresh-data/

Building SQL databases and OLAP/SSAS solutions has been a good career for me over the last 20 years.  That is still the "Rolls Royce" solution if you have the time and money.  But after 20 years I am still learning as it is a technically challenging area.  If you don't already have those skills, I suggest Power BI would be a more productive path.

Comment: Perfect. Thank you. I have spent the day with Power BI, and now have my logs transferred to Power BI realtime using the REST api :) The only problem now is that I will add about 500.000 records on an average day, so If I don't delete anything I will after some months reach the 10GB limit. Any idea how I can solve this? Seems like it is not possible to delete rows from a dataset (the only option is to remove all rows).

Comment: The REST API is quite new and has a "Version 1" feel. I wouldn't recommend it for a production scenario at this stage, especially at those volumes. I was imagining the "traditional Power BI" route of files loaded using Power BI Desktop, with the report published to Power BI web, and refreshed using a Gateway. You can point Power BI Desktop at a folder of files and filter the list of files found to drop old content.

Answer (score 1):

You absolutely will want to store your logs in a SQL OLTP database. The very nature of a log table is transactional, you will be constantly updating it and will benefit from the speed of commits.

The reporting speed issue you mention can be resolved by building an OLAP data warehouse on top of the log database. It seems your data model is quite simplistic so it wouldn't be very much development work to implement.

The *only* way to get real-time reporting is to build your reports on top of the OLTP database. If you can live with a small delay, most places opt to rebuild their cubes overnight which will provide near instant reports on a 24h delay.

Apologies for the conceptual response but short of designing your infrastructure for you, I think that's as far as can be gone in the Q&A format.

Comment: OK, thank you so much:) I will check if I can get this working by keeping the log in the sql database I'm currently using, but then transfer the logs to the azure sql datawarehouse for reporting. I can live with a small delay, but not 24 hours. 1 hour is my maximum. Hopefully that is possible.

Comment: Sure, it just means setting up an hourly job to update your dimension tables.